# Simple bind of the value of this to equal this in the upper scope in React to set the state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the value of 'this' to never be undefined:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      toChange: "needs changing"
    };
    this.next = this.next.bind(this); // is this needed?
  }

  next() {
    console.log("this one: ", this);

    const testFn = () => {
      console.log("this two: ", this);
    };

    if (true) {
      testFn();

      console.log('this 3', this);

      /*
      this.setState{(
        toChange: "changed!" // this errors - unknown reason why
      )}*/

      const testFnTwo = function() {
        console.log('this 4', this);// how to make 'this' be the same value as in the upper scope?
      [1].forEach(function() {
        console.log('this 5: ', this); // how to make 'this' be the same value as in the upper scope?
      });
      }();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.next()}</div>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wf2dkz - click on 'console' at the bottom right

How can I set the value of 'this' inside `testFnTwo` and the forEach function inside of it to match the same 'this' value in the outer execution context?

Another key aim of this test is to change the state of `toChange` (as per this commented out code):

```
/*
this.setState{(
   toChange: "changed!" // this errors - unknown reason why
)}
*/
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work also? I've seen this be used in loads of demos elsewhere on the web, but for some reason I get this error:

```
Error in index.js (30:19)
'types' can only be used in a .ts file.
```

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `next()` function itself to arrow function and inner scope as well to arrow function so that you could get the right scope to `this` keyword.

Also there is an error in `this.setState` because the brackets were misplaced and it should be like,

```
this.setState({
        toChange: "changed!" // this errors - unknown reason why
      })
```

And hence component would look like,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      toChange: "needs changing"
    };
  }

  next = () => {
    console.log("this one: ", this);

    const testFn = () => {
      console.log("this two: ", this);
    };

    if (true) {
      testFn();

      console.log('this 3', this);


      this.setState({
        toChange: "changed!" // this errors - unknown reason why
      })

      const testFnTwo = () => {
        console.log('this 4', this);// how to make 'this' be the same value as in the upper scope?
      [1].forEach(() => {
        console.log('this 5: ', this); // how to make 'this' be the same value as in the upper scope?
      });
      };

      testFnTwo();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.next()}</div>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Also it is not best practice to call the `{this.next()}` method like this inside `render` because it will make infinite call to the `next()` function.

This scenario leads to the error `Maximum update depth exceeded.` .. So you should look into it and fix as per your requirement.

You could look at the console to have `this` value in all scenarios in this [**Forked stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zdnvjc)

Comment: very helpful and informative, thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1):

*This 1, 2, 3* will be the *"this" you want*. However *this 4 & 5* are inside a `function` and `this` will be *rebound*. To prevent that behaviour use a [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
const testFnTwo = (() => {
    console.log('this 4', this);
    [1].forEach(() => {
        console.log('this 5: ', this);
    });
})();
```

And the reason for the errors in `setState` call is that your brackets are the wrong way round. Should be `({` not `{(`:

```js
this.setState({
   toChange: "changed!"
});
```